# Changing List View Selected Row Color

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey Guys i was struggling from past 4 days for this Problem and No where the Full Solution was given so finally i am done with this issue and want to share the Code with you.

Comment: Hi Narendra, I can help you. Show me your code

Comment: can you share your code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
LinearLayout newRow = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
newRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
if(i % 2 != 0) {
    newRow.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(/* your color here: e.g., R.color.rowcols*/));
}
```

Using this in a loop where `i` is the incrementer, you can change every other row you add to be a different color.  I used LinearLayouts and added things to them (then added the LinearLayouts to a scrollable parent LinearLayout), but a similar approach should be accomplishable for ListViews.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved this Problem see guys i am giving the full code for this problem let me know if any one of you still face problem with this....

### *This is how my Activity looks alike see-->*******

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity implements Observer,
        OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener,
        {

   //My adapter where my selected position will be hold


    private MySimpleAdapter adapter;
ListView listViewMsgs = null;

protected Context activity;

protected int position = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message);


}
```

//Initialize your cursor adapter after getting the data from the server.

```
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {

        String[] from = new String[] { "sender_number", "display_name",
                "access_number", "timestamp", "message_type" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.photomsg, R.id.display_name,
                R.id.access_number, R.id.timestamp1, R.id.message_type };
        adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, this.model,
                R.layout.messagelist, mymsglist, from, to);
        listViewMsgs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMsgs);
        listViewMsgs.setAdapter(adapter);
        listViewMsgs.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);
        listViewMsgs.setDescendantFocusability(ListView.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

}
```

//Your own Adapter where we will set the selected position and all.

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {


    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, MessageModel model, int layout,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mymsglist, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, mymsglist, layout, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.mymsglist = mymsglist;
        this.model = model;
    }
        **//Add this code inside your own CursorAdapter.....
         //set the selected position of the row over here.

    private int selectedPos = 0;//-1    // init value for not-selected
    public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
        // inform the view of this change
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public int getSelectedPosition(){
        return selectedPos;
    }
    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }**

        //One thing which most of the android developer i think dont know is when getView is called 
        //when you are making a ListView.....the answer is it will get called to draw each row of the ListView.

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          //The get view is called everytime a row is drawn and that is how the color of each row is drawn.


        if(selectedPos == position){
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }else{
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }
        return row;
    }

}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    //on selection of a row basically we are setting the position now when getView will draw this this
        //this row it will change the selected row color.
    adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);

    MessageActivity.this.position = position;

}
```

Comment: Please try to read the commented lines also to get the better idea about the solution of this problem.